# Chrome extension to detect locale of current tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to show the locale(lang attribute of html source code) of the tab selected and display it in my popup.html of Chrome-Extension. For doing this. My popup.html is:

```
<div id="pageLocale">Page Locale is: <b>  <script src="write.js"></script></b></div>
```

My write.js is:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"document.write(document.documentElement.lang)"});
```

If I use this, I get the content of my selected tab all blank and only the locale string. I understand what is the issue here.
I want to know, how I can extract lang attribute using  "document.documentElement.lang" for the current tab and return it to my popup.html. The current tab selected should not go blank when I click chrome-extension icon. Please help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `document.write` in `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, you're overwriting the content of the document (as you've observed). Often, you should not use `document.write`.

And don't use `document.documentElement.lang`, because it can be empty if not set by the page. Instead, use [`chrome.tabs.detectLanguage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-detectLanguage). Here's an example:

```
// write.js
(function() {
    var thisScriptElement = document.currentScript;
    chrome.tabs.detectLanguage(null, function(language) {
        var node = document.createTextNode(language);
        // Replace <script> with the text
        thisScriptElement.parentNode.replaceChild(node, thisScriptElement);
    });
})();
```

If you *really* want to get the value of the `lang` attribute (even if it is an empty string), then you need to use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` as follows:

```
// write.js
(function() {
    var thisScriptElement = document.currentScript;
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code: 'document.documentElement.lang;'
    }, function(result) {
        var language = result[0]; // Last expression's result in the top frame.
        var node = document.createTextNode(language);
        // Replace <script> with the text
        thisScriptElement.parentNode.replaceChild(node, thisScriptElement);
    });
})();
```

Comment: Hi Rob,
Thanks for the prompt reply. I am using "document.documentElement.lang" knowingly and my requirement is to showup the lang attribute value even if it is empty/undefined/invalid which detectLanguage fails to. Can you please help with implementation using "document.documentElement.lang".

Comment: Thanks a Tonnnn. Rob.. Made my day.. was struggling since noon :) :)